# The bed of my Ender-4 does not go down during printing!

Tags: marlin, z-axis, bed, creality-ender-4

I am using an Ender-4 with MKS Marlin Firmware and an MKS Rovin V3 Motherboard. It took me a long time to get Marlin set up correctly, but now I am apparently on the way. I calibrated the bed and to test it I went to print the cube_XYZ, I noticed that the bed didn't go down during the print, even though the display was showing that the Z was increasing.

Has anyone experienced this situation and/or can give me some advice?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that the Z stepper motor doesn't work during the printing and after. Because I've tried to move the axis and it didn't work. So I reset the printer and try to move the Z-axis again, and it worked.

Comment: Please [edit] and add new info to the question and *not* in the comments. Thank you.